# Shower tile cracking horizontally in two corners

Tags: bathroom, shower, structural, ceramic-tile, cracks

I was cleaning my shower today and noticed two new hairline tile cracks (they weren’t there when I cleaned last week). Both are in the third row up and both cracks span the corners. 6 tiles total are cracked. See photos.

The bathroom was fully remodeled less than a year ago. It’s an old house (1919) but no major concerns from our inspection. This particular bathroom happens to be in an overhang-style addition - which concerns me. Again, no issues were brought up with this addition in the property inspection. You can see in the exterior photo where the bathroom is situated in the addition - I outlined the rough shower location in red. This photo was taken during renovations which is why the ceiling is open (but maybe helpful to see the joists as well?)

As far as I can tell, the work my GC did was very good and I was happy with him. I’m maybe less concerned about proper shower construction and more concerned with structural issues. And please note, I live in a very dry area (Los Angeles) and we has what must have been record-breaking rains a few weeks ago. So perhaps settling brought on by the massive amounts of water? The house has been noticeably creaking/groaning since the rains.

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

[image: Shower stall overview] [image: Detail of cracked tiles]
<sup>Click images to embiggen</sup>
[image: Detail from another angle] [image: porch ceiling showing where shower is above]

Comment: Please post your photos here in the question using the editor.

Comment: You indicate "two _new_ hairline cracks" are there others that were there before or are these the first you've seen?

Comment: FreeMan those were the first I’ve seen. I just meant “new” in that they weren’t there a week ago.

Comment: Last year I was renting a recently-flipped house in Ventura that had the exact same tiny cracks in the shower and backsplash tiles.  A little cracking would seem normal to me as the nice rigid cement board and tiles eventually settle in to comply with the old framing.  It did always puzzle me why the cracks were showing up in the tiles themselves rather than in the grout.  Since that addition is new, it would have some settling to do, especially as you stated the dry ground expanding with the recent rains.

Comment: Something else just occurred to me about those support posts.  I can't tell from the photo, but are they sitting directly on the patio or do they go through and down into the ground to a concrete footing?

If they are not going all the way down to a footing, it would explain the movement as the ground expands and contracts from moisture.  We don't really worry about a frost line in coastal SoCal, but expansive soils will still move around a little with rains.

Comment: I am not an expert on tiles, but I guess the high humidity has gotten to the back board, which has then expanded from heat and resulted in a slight bow that stretched the rigid tiles at the corner.

Comment: Chris I think you’re on to something. The support posts for the addition have their own footings, underneath that brick/concrete patio they are set in concrete I believe (there are metal posts but I had them wrapped in wood). Not sure how far down they go, the addition was built around 1968 if I remember correctly. I’m hoping it just has to do with all that rain, and of course the clay soil we have here in SoCal. That sounds better than my bathroom being at risk of imminent collapse…